# change layout of products

Tags: product, category, layout

I set a layout for a category(parent) and then I want to set this layout for all the sub category(child), in addition I want to set a particulary layout for all product of this categories.
For the first (parent) category I set:

```
-anchor
-2 column
-layout:

<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/bacheca.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="product_list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>catalog/product/bacheca-list.phtml</template>
     </action>
</reference>
<reference name="product.info">
     <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>catalog/product/confronta-view.phtml</template>
     </action>
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="/catalog/product/view/media_bacheca.phtml" />
</reference>
```

for child category I set get design from parent, it is all perfect but I need to set 1column on product view, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `<layout>` node, write

`<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>`

Comment: in local.xml there is already this setting, I think the problem is that I set 2column on category and I set it also for product